# Find view off screen

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

Please tell me if there is any way to find a view that is placed off the screen. For example: we have a screen size of 240x320, but some view have a size of -800x-400. How can I find this? I use uiautomator, but only objects in sight are returned to him. Thanks!

Comment: why are you placing the view off the screen to hide it? why not do view.setVisibility(GONE)

Comment: I'm not Android developer, i think that can be possible, and i try find this.